# What can I change in order that Compdef can bind my function?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have created some console commands in PHP. I need to use autocompletion when I launch my tasks.

I used `alias otra="php console.php"` in my `.zshrc` file.

The function itself seems to work but when I type my command name 'otra', there is only folders autocompletion...which is completely irrelevant in my case.

```sh
#compdef _otra otra

function _otra {
     local line
     _arguments -C \
         "1: :(createAction createBundle)" \
         "*::arg:->args"
}
```

I want to only have the two words `createAction` and `createBundle` to appear when I type `otra` and type .

**EDIT**

Ok, it is what I was thinking...if I remove my alias, the completion works but I cannot remove it since `otra` is not a valid command...

I tried to use `setopt no_complete_aliases` as I see it in another Stackoverflow post but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it was related to the alias but I did not have to set `setopt no_complete_aliases`in my case but pretty much the contrary...
After I put `setopt complete_aliases` in my `.zshrc` file, it works :D